# Help with limit of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x \csc 10x}{\cos20x}$$

I'm unsure of how to solve this. I think if I were to simplify it, it would be:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x \csc 10x}{\cos20x} = \lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1}{x\sin10x})\div(\frac{1}{\cos20x})$$

$$\implies\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x\sin 10x}\times\frac{\cos20x}{1}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos20x}{x\sin 10x}.$$

Is this correct? How do I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: $x\csc(10x)\neq\dfrac{1}{x\sin(10x)}$.  It should be $x\csc(10x) = \dfrac{x}{\sin(10 x)}$

Comment: How did the cosine term end up in the numerator? That division sign is incorrect, should be multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x \csc 10x}{\cos20x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sin10x\cos20x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{10x}{\sin10x}\frac{1}{10\cos20x}=\frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: thanks! How did you get the $10$ in the numerator in $\frac{10}{\sin 10x}$?

Comment: Yeah, remember @user436158 that the limit of products is the product of limits!

Comment: He multiplied the numerator and the denominator by 10, which is technically multiplying by 1 but in that way he gets the rational term, $\frac{10}{sin(10x)}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
       &  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x \csc 10x}{\cos 20 x}  && \\
 ~ = ~ &  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{\sin 10 x \cos 20 x} && [\text{definition of csc}] \\
 ~ = ~ & \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{5(3\cos 30 x - \cos 10x)} && [\text{indeterminate form}] \\
 ~ = ~ & \frac{1}{10} && [\text{continuity of cos}]
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks! How did you get $5(3\cos 30x - \cos 10x)$ in the denominator?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \sin 10x \cos 20x \right) = 5(3\cos 30x - \cos 10x)$

Answer (score 0):

just calculate the Taylor series $$\frac{113753750 x^6}{189}+\frac{33175 x^4}{9}+\frac{65 x^2}{3}+\frac{1}{10}$$ and take the limit